# Applet to Control Brightness on Each Monitor

Tags: debian, awesome, brightness

Using [Awesome](https://awesomewm.org/), I'm looking for a system tray applet that can control the brightness of each monitor. Using apt search I found a package called budgie-brightness-controller-applet, which was intended for the budgie desktop, but I read it can work independently. However, after installing it, I cannot figure out how to launch it. I'm hoping it will launch into awesome's system tray similar to how volumeicon-alsa does, but would like to know of any way to access it and try it out short of installing an entire desktop to do so.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687453/